# Ember redirect only firing the first time you enter the route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an 'about' resource that has about.philosophy and about.staff routes nested under it. In the AboutRoute there is a redirect so that when you click the 'about' link on the nav the app redirects to about.philosophy.

```
Ew.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    this.transitionTo('about.philosophy');
  }
});
```

However, if you are currently inside one of the nested routes and click the 'about' link in the nav again, instead of redirecting you to about.philosophy it renders '/about', which doesn't have a template so its a broken page.

How come this redirect doesn't work after you try and enter the AboutRoute a second time?

**UPDATE**

Dan's solution fixed this issue but it also resulted in a broken subnav. I changed my AboutRoute, which has the subnav code, to AboutIndexRoute and the subnav no longer shows up:

```
Ew.AboutIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function(){
    this.controllerFor('application').set('renderAboutSubNav', true);
  },
  deactivate: function(){
    this.controllerFor('application').set('renderAboutSubNav', false);
  },
  redirect: function(){
    this.transitionTo('about.philosophy');
  }
});
```

Then in application.hbs I have:

```
{{#if renderAboutSubNav}}
  {{render 'about/subnav'}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: can u produce a fiddle for it... interesting problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend putting your `redirect` on an `AboutIndexRoute`, so that it will only be invoked when the user ends up at `/about` and not a child route. For instance, you probably want to allow users to navigate directly to `/about/staff`, and you won't want `redirect` to be invoked as the `AboutRoute` is entered on the way to the `AboutStaffRoute`.

By the way, `redirect` is now deprecated in favor of the `afterModel` hook (although `afterModel` internally calls `redirect` for now).

Comment: When I implemented your solution the redirect problem was fixed however it broke a subnav on my application template.

I changed AboutRoute to AboutIndexRoute and the subnav no longer shows up. I'll add more details to my first question.

Comment: The reason your subnav doesn't show up is because the AboutIndexRoute is not entered on the way to your sub-routes. You'll need to keep your rendering code in AboutRoute and your redirect code in AboutIndexRoute.